# How do I layer parts using MEF?

Tags: .net, mef

I'm working on some example programs using MEF.  In the simplest example I wrote, I've got an `IDoSomething` interface which looks like so:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
   void DoIt();
}
```

and a class which implements it that looks like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDoSomething))]
public class TestClass : IDoSomething
{
    public void DoIt()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("TestClass::DoIt");
    }
}
```

and a class that loads the plugin that looks like this:

```
public class PluginManager
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IDoSomething))]
    private IEnumerable<IDoSomething> plugins;

    public void Run()
    {
        Compose();
        foreach (var plugin in plugins)
        {
            plugin.DoSomething();

        }
    }

    private void Compose()
    {
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\");
        var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }

}
```

And this seems to work, but now what I'd like to do is extend on of my concrete plugins to itself have a plugin, something like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDoSomething))]
public class TestClass2 : IDoSomething
{
    [Import(typeof(IDoAnotherThing))]
    public IDoAnotherThing Plugin { get; set; }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestClass2::DoIt");
        Plugin.Func();
    }
}
```

where `IDoAnotherThing` looks like this:

```
public interface IDoAnotherThing
{
    void Func();
}
```

and my concrete implementation of that looks like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDoAnotherThing))]
public class AnotherPlugin: IDoAnotherThing
{
    public void Func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AnotherPlugin::Func");
    }
}
```

The behavior I see when I run this is that my `TestClass2` instance gets created and its `DoIt` function is called but its `AnotherPlugin` instance never gets called.  I see that the catalog has the `AnotherPlugin` listed.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I recreated this without any code changes and it worked fine for me. You've specified that the `TestClass2` instance is created, but the `AnotherPlugin` instance doesn't get called? It would have fallen over if if it couldn't set the import for the `Plugin` property. Something else must be occurring. Can we see some more code?

Answer (score 0):

I *thought* was was specifying this correctly and it turns out that I was, but as Matthew Abbott commented above, something else was in fact occurring.  In this case, it was the fact that my concrete class plugins weren't all ending up in the same directory and as a result, my app wasn't discovery the correct one.  Live and learn.  Once I made sure that I had the latest of all of those assemblies, everything worked just fine.